# Prometheus, OR Vector(0)

Tags: database, monitoring, prometheus

I am trying to run this query in Prometheus. But I need to add "OR Vector(0)" operation, so in case there is no value available (NaN) it will hit a `0`.

Really appreciate if you can tell me how to use `OR Vector(0)` operator here.

```
https://prometheus.test.com/api/v1/query_range?query=histogram_quantile(0.9,sum%20by(le)(rate(test_duration_bucket-part1-[1m])))&start=startTime&end=endTime&step=1m",
```

Thanks in advance.